# How do I set up a FLEX_HOME environment variable in Flash Builder

Tags: ant, flash-builder

When I try to run Ant build script in Flash Builder error will generate. So I put `export FLEX_HOME=/Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4.7/sdks/4.6.0/` in my `.zshrc`. This works fine in command line, but doesn't in FB.

build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="helloworld" basedir="../" default="compile">
    <!-- Set up prefix for all environment variables -->
    <property environment="env" />
    <fail unless="env.FLEX_HOME" message="FLEX_HOME needs to be defined as an environment variable or in the Ant build." />
    <!-- Load user properties to overrride defaults -->
    <property file="${basedir}/build/build.properties" />
    <!-- System environment must contain FLEX_HOME variable that points to Flex SDK -->
    <property name="FLEX_HOME" location="${env.FLEX_HOME}" />
    <!-- Set up Flex tasks in Ant -->
    <taskdef resource="flexTasks.tasks" classpath="${FLEX_HOME}/ant/lib/flexTasks.jar" />

    <!-- Create directories needed for the build process -->
    <target name="init" description="Initializes project and destination folders.">
        <echo message="Project: ${ant.project.name}" />
        <echo message="Flex SDK: ${FLEX_HOME}" />
        <echo message="Flex home is ${env.FLEX_HOME}" />
        <delete dir="${bin.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${bin.dir}" />
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="init" description="Compiles the application.">
        <mxmlc file="${src.dir}/${application.name}.as" output="${bin.dir}/${application.name}.swf">
            <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml" />

            <source-path path-element="${src.dir}" />

        </mxmlc>    
        <echo message="The ${application.name}.swf has been created in ${bin.dir}" />
    </target>

</project>
```

And the error

```
Buildfile: /Users/gadzimari/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/helloworld/build/build.xml

BUILD FAILED
/Users/gadzimari/Documents/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/helloworld/build/build.xml:5: FLEX_HOME needs to be defined as an environment variable or in the Ant build.

Total time: 302 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark...

Should the declaration of the FLEX_HOME property be set using a value attribute as follows?

```
<property name="FLEX_HOME" value="${env.FLEX_HOME}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your FLEX_HOME similarly to how you set JAVA_HOME.

Go to your Users/{username} folder and find your ".bash_profile". If no bash profile exists there, make an empty one as a .txt file, save it, and then rename it from ".bash_profile.txt" to ".bash_profile".

Then add the following to your bash profile:

```
export FLEX_HOME=/{flex install path}
```

Replace the bracketed portion with the actual flex install path for your system, then save. To verify it, open a new command line and use the command "echo $FLEX_HOME". If it responds with /{flex install path}, then it is set properly.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this myself today after trying to pickup a super old project from years back. Haven't had Flex (errr... Flash Builder) installed on this machine in ages.

End up needing to alter the `build.properties` file with the following:

```
FLEX_HOME=/Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4.7/sdks/3.5.0
 FLEX_FW_VERSION = framework_3.5.0.12683
```

That did the trick for me.