# FLEX_HOME environment variable Error

Tags: xml, flash, apache-flex, ant

Running into an issue here.  I'm trying to build an ant build.xml file, but I'm running into the following error:

`You must set the FLEX_HOME environment variable to your SDK's home directory`

Based on everything I've run across, I'm supposed to set the FLEX_HOME variable in my .bash_profile, .profile, or .bashrc file (which I've set it in all three but still no luck).  I have it set to the following:

`export FLEX_HOME=/Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4.7/sdks/4.6.0`

I've also tried like this:

`export FLEX_HOME="/Applications/Adobe Flash Builder 4.7/sdks/4.6.0"`

No luck though.  I had some other compile errors in my build.xml file, but making a few hard coded references in my build.xml seemed to have fixed some of the issues with the exception of the one above).  Can someone give a little guidance on what I might be doing wrong??

Modified build.xml
http://jsfiddle.net/jdubba/mc3yesqq/

Original build.xml
http://jsfiddle.net/jdubba/bp5fx8a6/

This is the closest reference I could find on the issue:
 [How do I set up a FLEX_HOME environment variable in Flash Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277539/how-do-i-set-up-a-flex-home-environment-variable-in-flash-builder)

Answer (score 0):

After days of research, I changed my build.xml back to the original build and under my "ant" window I right clicked on my ant build and selected:

`Run As > External Tools Configurations...`

Clicked on the "Class Path" tab and under "Ant Home" folder selection, I added the following .jar files:

`ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar`

`flexTasks.jar`

Then ran my ant task and I was able to compile with no build errors.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use escape characters nor the quotation marks when setting Windows environment variable `FLASH_HOME`. I had a bad headache because of that when tried to use it with maven ( in `maven-antrun-plugin` ). Use plain text as it appears in the path.